# Selection dialog in Windows Forms

Tags: c#

There is a file selection dialog OpenFileDialog. There is a folder selection dialog FolderBrowserDialog. I need to implement the selection of both files and folders in one dialog with the return of an array of full paths. I have been trying to find something similar on the Internet for a long time, but so far without success...

Comment: You you need to be able to select multiple files and multiple folders together from the dialog?

Comment: Yes. I see that standard tools do not provide this. I am planning to write a GUI for robocopy. I think writing a selection dialog from scratch is superfluous and very labor-intensive.

Answer (score 0):

There ist no native Control to select Files and folders. But you can concat the Dialogs, so First use a folder selection Dialog, then the file selection Dialog within the selected folder. If you cancel the File selection you return the folder. Or use some custom control Like this: https://github.com/scottwis/OpenFileOrFolderDialog

Answer (score 0):

You can use visual basic filelistbox and dirlistbox in a windows form and design your dialog box.there is no default dialog for your question.

.net class for c# is : Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6

this link can help ==> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.compatibility.vb6.filelistbox?view=netframework-4.8

I hope this answer is useful for you.Let me know if you need sample code.